# Solr CDCR (cross data center replication) target and its commits

Tags: solr, solrcloud

How does a Solr CDCR target cluster handle commits? The commit settings are the same as on the CDCR source, where the Solr admin UI shows freshly indexed documents with hardly any delay. Both settings are

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
  <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
<autoSoftCommit>
  <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>
```

with the `${solr*maxTime}` unset as far as I can tell. (I am a bit surprised anyway, given the settings, that I see results shortly after indexing on the source cluster:-(

Yet on the target cluster, I seem to *never* get a commit, certainly not within 15 seconds as the default suggests. I know  the data is available, since it appears right after a manual commit.

Any idea how to configure the target to actually perform any commits?

Comment: Do you havei it resolved?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue. Adding softcommit to 15s helped me:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"set-property":{"updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime":1500}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/<yourcollection>/config
```

I found in some [forum](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/solrcloud-Auto-commit-doesn-t-seem-reliable-td4374606.html) hint to restart server, did not help me.

Comment: Restart server is quite a silly idea.:-) soft-commit helps, strange?